# Use underscores or capitals in PL/SQL variables names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Should variable names in PL/SQL use underscores or capital letters to separate words?

`this_is_my_variable` or `thisIsMyVariable`?

I can't find a clear answer to this and I've seen both.

Comment: SQL as a domain language is case-insensitive, and I believe PL/SQL is too.  What might this suggest about camel-casing?

Comment: Well, it just means that camel-casing would end up being formatting only, and have no actual effect on the variable declaration (staying out of argument about case-sensitivity in programming languages).  If you have a string that can be legitimately cased in multiple places, it will be - this may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PL/SQL uses the first style: `this_is_my_variable`.

It is the universally acepted coding style for PL/SQL.

All documentation and sample code is written like that. All Oracle documentation and courses on PL/SQL use that convention.

Just like Java uses the other one ( camel case ).

Comment: I guess this is because SQL is case insensitive and some IDEs (like Oracle SQL Developer) transform everything into all caps.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend investing in [Joe Celko's SQL Programming Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887975).

Basically echoing @user1598390, you should avoid Camel Case and jaming everything together.

Camel Case has numerous issues, primarily:

1. There has to be an agreed format : upcCode, UpcCode, UPCCode. Causes confusion and you end up with multiple versions of the same variable.
2. Studies have found that it slows [reading](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1969-10728-001) and [writing](https://doi.org/10.3758/BF03198246).

No Spaces:

1. This is a hold over from punchcards where you reduced space due to the limited number of columns.
2. We don't use punchcards.

Comment: It's true, we don't have to spare space anymore. My main (though not big) issue with underscores is, that it's not the easiest character to type on an Italian keyboard. I don't how it's on English keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a naming convenience, use whatever fits with your other team members.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you. Most PL/SQL you'll see uses snake case (i.e., `variables_like_this`). Personally, I don't like this style so use camel case (i.e., `likeThis`).

Answer (score 1):

Follow your team coding rules will be the first choice.